# Error uploading my ionic app apk to google play console

Tags: android, ionic3, ionic-native, google-play-console

When i tried to upload ky signed ionic apk on alpha release in google play console it showed an error "package name already exist" how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the app package names are uniques, that error appears you because an app with the seame package name already exist in Play Store.
So you just need to change the package name in config.xml and rebuild your Apk.
Upload again with no problem.

Here a link with the conventions of Package Names to make them unique:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html